# Qual o motivo de se precisar de 5 pontos para responder e 50 pontos para comentar?

Tags: debate

Isso não faz sentido pra mim, responder uma pergunta ao meu ver exige bem mais conhecimento do que comentar uma. Além do mais, ao comentar eu posso tirar dúvidas para elaborar uma resposta melhor.

Comment: Relacionada [Porque necessitamos de tanta reputação para comentar?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5058/91)

Comment: Duplicada, vou remover.

Comment: Restaurei a pergunta porque duplicatas são úteis para ajudar os outros a encontrar conteúdo (principalmente via mecanismos de busca)

Comment: A parte dos comentários já foi abordada na pergunta duplicata. Quanto a questão dos 5 pontos para responder, na verdade são 5 pontos para participar no meta - sugiro abrir uma nova pergunta para esclarecer esse ponto caso ainda tenha alguma dúvida.